# Can a script be added to a Google Slide allowing it to advance to the next slide only with a specific alphanumeric input in a text box?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I hope this is not inappropriate, I do not code but am willing to learn if I can create a script that would allow me to create a CBT using Google Slides, where a specific input would be required in a text box for it to advance to the next slide and/or give an error message. The background would be a picture of the program page that would require specific input. I have been unable to find any format in the base Slide programming to achieve this. I do not have any code to show. Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Google Slides doesn't allow custom scripts to control next/back slides presentation actions.

Comment: What's a CBT?...

Comment: Thank you for the replies. A CBT = Computer-Based Training. A self-initiated learning method that allows engagement and interaction by the learner without the aid of a facilitator.